# CBPeripheral services are not rediscovered properly after change

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS Swift 5 project on which `CBCentralManager` is used to connect to a `BLE` device. There is a write `CBCharacteristic` which should be used to write a certain value from the iOS device and after a successful write, the device changes its services adding a new service into its `GATT` table. CoreBluetooth seems to not recognize the updated services. The BLE device is paired with iOS.

Things tried and what happened:

- If you don't implement `didModifyServices` from `CBPeripheralDelegate`, CoreBluetooth complains that the services changed but you don't have a method to handle these changes
- If you implement `didModifyServices`, it never gets called and the above message never gets shown
- Tried manually rediscovering services after a successful write but the `CBPerpiheral` returns the old service only, despite the BLE device actually having another one now in the `GATT` table, as if `CoreBluetooth` caches the old services and doesn't actually rediscover them
- Tried disconnecting and discarding the `CBPeripheral` instance, in order to rediscover it and reconnect - in this case, the peripheral never gets rediscovered again after disconnecting.

Any ideas what could be possibly done to be able to rediscover a new service?

Relevant CoreBluetooth code:

```
enum BluetoothStateChange
{
    case unknown
    case unsupported
    case unauthorized
    case poweredOff
}

class BluetoothCentralService: NSObject
{
    var onStateChange: ((BluetoothStateChange) -> Void)?
    var onServicesScannedPeripheralsUpdate: ((_ peripherals: [UUID]) -> Void)?
    var onCharacteristicsDiscovered: ((_ peripheral: UUID, _ service: CBUUID, _ characteristics: [CBUUID]) -> Void)?
    var onCharacteristicWriteFinished: ((_ peripheral: UUID, _ characteristic: CBUUID, _ isSuccessful: Bool) -> Void)?
    var onCharacteristicReadFinished: ((_ peripheral: UUID, _ characteristic: CBUUID, _ value: Data?) -> Void)?

    private var connectingPeripherals = Set<CBPeripheral>()
    private var connectedPeripherals = Set<CBPeripheral>()
    private var servicesDiscoveredPeripherals = Set<CBPeripheral>()
    private var ignoredPeripherals = Set<CBPeripheral>()

    private let central: CBCentralManager
    private let logger: LoggerProtocol

    var rememberedDeviceUUID: UUID?

    init(central: CBCentralManager, logger: LoggerProtocol, rememberedDeviceUUID: UUID? = nil)
    {
        self.central = central
        self.logger = logger
        self.rememberedDeviceUUID = rememberedDeviceUUID

        super.init()

        central.delegate = self
    }

    func ignore(_ uuid: UUID)
    {
        guard
            let peripheral = connectedPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == uuid })
                ?? servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == uuid })
        else {
            return
        }

        ignoredPeripherals.insert(peripheral)
        servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.remove(peripheral)
        central.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }

    func services(for uuid: UUID) -> [CBUUID]
    {
        return servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.first { $0.identifier == uuid }?.services?.map { $0.uuid } ?? []
    }

    func discoverCharacteristics(for peripheralUuid: UUID, service uuid: CBUUID)
    {
        guard
            let peripheral = servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == peripheralUuid }),
            let service = peripheral.service(with: uuid)
        else {
            return
        }

        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    }

    func write(
        to peripheralUuid: UUID,
        service serviceUuid: CBUUID,
        characteristic characteristicUuid: CBUUID,
        value: Data,
        type: CBCharacteristicWriteType
    ){
        guard
            let peripheral = servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == peripheralUuid }),
            let service = peripheral.service(with: serviceUuid),
            let characteristic = service.characteristics?.first(where: { $0.uuid == characteristicUuid })
        else {
            return
        }

        peripheral.writeValue(value, for: characteristic, type: type)
    }

    func read(from peripheralUuid: UUID, service serviceUuid: CBUUID, characteristic characteristicUuid: CBUUID)
    {
        guard
            let peripheral = servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == peripheralUuid }),
            let service = peripheral.service(with: serviceUuid),
            let characteristic = service.characteristics?.first(where: { $0.uuid == characteristicUuid })
        else {
            return
        }

        peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
    }
}

extension BluetoothCentralService: CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
    {
        switch central.state
        {
        case .resetting:
            break
        case .unknown:
            onStateChange?(.unknown)
        case .unsupported:
            onStateChange?(.unsupported)
        case .unauthorized:
            onStateChange?(.unauthorized)
        case .poweredOff:
            onStateChange?(.poweredOff)
            connectedPeripherals = []
            servicesDiscoveredPeripherals = []
            ignoredPeripherals = []
            onServicesScannedPeripheralsUpdate?([])
        case .poweredOn:
            scanRemembered()
        default:
            logger.log(.warning, "\(#function): Unhandled state type.")
        }
    }

    private func scanRemembered()
    {
        guard
            let uuid = rememberedDeviceUUID,
            let peripheral = central.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [uuid]).first
        else {
            scanConnected(); return
        }

        connect(peripheral)
    }

    private func scanConnected()
    {
        let connected = central.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [])

        connectedPeripherals.formUnion(connected)
        connectedPeripherals.forEach { $0.discoverServices(nil) }

        scanNew()
    }

    private func scanNew()
    {
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
    }

    private func connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)
    {
        guard
            !ignoredPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !connectingPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !connectedPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.contains(peripheral)
        else {
            return
        }

        connectingPeripherals.insert(peripheral)
        peripheral.delegate = self

        central.connect(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(
        _ central: CBCentralManager,
        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
        advertisementData: [String : Any],
        rssi RSSI: NSNumber
    ){
        guard
            !ignoredPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !connectingPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !connectedPeripherals.contains(peripheral),
            !servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.contains(peripheral)
        else {
            return
        }

        connect(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
    {
        connectingPeripherals.remove(peripheral)
        connectedPeripherals.insert(peripheral)

        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)
    {
        connectedPeripherals.remove(peripheral)
    }
}

extension BluetoothCentralService: CBPeripheralDelegate
{
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
    {
        guard error == nil else { return }

        servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.insert(peripheral)
        connectedPeripherals.remove(peripheral)

        onServicesScannedPeripheralsUpdate?(servicesDiscoveredPeripherals.map { $0.identifier })
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)
    {
        onCharacteristicsDiscovered?(
            peripheral.identifier,
            service.uuid,
            service.characteristics?.compactMap { $0.uuid } ?? []
        )
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
    {
        onCharacteristicWriteFinished?(peripheral.identifier, characteristic.uuid, error == nil)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
    {
        onCharacteristicReadFinished?(peripheral.identifier, characteristic.uuid, characteristic.value)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didModifyServices invalidatedServices: [CBService])
    {
        // This never gets called if it's actually implemented here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI I ended up modifying the code on the BLE device side so it registers both services and doesn't manipulate the GATT table. Still no idea why iOS is having problems with updating the service list.

Comment: Does the peripheral update its advertisement when it adds the service?  I've noticed that if a peripheral has 2 services but is only advertising 1 (or vice versa), iOS seems to treat that as an invalid configuration, and tells you the peripheral has 0 services...sometimes.  In general, I've seen lots of behavior in this whole stack that isn't documented anywhere, so it's been challenging to accomplish certain things without a lot of trial and error.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have an app where each device is a central and a peripheral. If I close the app on one device, the other app notices the disconnect and changes the values of the subscribed characteristics. If I start the one that I killed again, when it subscribes to those characteristics again, it gets the values at the time the app was killed rather then getting fresh values. I'm still mulling over how best to resolve this problem.

Comment: @bartlomiej.n have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I don’t remember it anymore, but it looked like a bug with CoreBluetooth. The Android device code didn’t have this problem. Like I said I just went in and adjusted the embedded device BLE code so it worked well on both platforms, so I’m afraid I can’t help you with this.